Equivalence of Pauli equation and photon picture
The motion of a charge in EM potential is described by the Pauli equation ( which is the non relativistic limit of Dirac eqn). On the other hand, we know that the EM potential is nothing else than the sum of EM potentials of photons: $A_\mu(t,\bar{x}) = \int d^3\bar{k} N_{\bar{k}} \epsilon_\mu(\bar{k}) exp(i\omega_k t - i\bar{k} \bar{x})$, where $N_{\bar{k}}$ is the photon number. The absorption/emission from the field corresponds to the change of the numbers $N_{\bar{k}}$.
Question:  How to see that Pauli equation follows from the photon picture?

The Pauli equation is a description of the charges whilst you are talking about changing the way you model the field. In a sense this makes this things simple: you take the classical limit of the EM field and then plug that classical field into the Pauli equation

@BySymmetry Thanks for your answer. No, this is not what I am asking. Rather, I am trying to understand how absorption/emission of single light quanta from the ensemble lead to the spacetime dependent wave function of the electron. Or, put another way, how to go from Fock space of QED to the Pauli equation.
